# Change embed pdfviewer in emacs

Tags: emacs

Usually I read pdf with okular, for I can customized the background color and text color. Now I am working on latex with a preview pane on the right of the window, the background color is just too white!

I need to change the color of the backgroud and the text color, or if I can change that pdfviewer to okular(need embed in emacs).

I wonder how I can do this. I am using latex-preview-pane minor mode, and AUCTex on emacs 24.

Here is the emacs window, the pdf hurts my eyes!

[image: lllll]

Comment: I don't think you can embed an external viewer in an Emacs window.  The embedded preview is probably a *.png file or similar low resolution image file that is being generated and displayed.

Comment: As far as I know the xwidget branch is currently the only way to embed other applications into emacs: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsXWidgets.

Comment: Here is an interesting portion of `preview.el` that you may wish to take a look at:  `(defface preview-face '((((background dark)) (:background "dark slate gray")) (t (:background "beige"))) "Face to use for the preview source." :group 'preview-appearance)`

Comment: `(setq TeX-view-program-list '(("Evince" "evince --page-index=%(outpage) %o")))`
`(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "Evince")))` from [here](http://superuser.com/questions/253525/emacs-auctex-how-do-i-open-the-pdf-in-evince-at-the-current-cursor-position?rq=1). Before you do have a look at [pdf-tools](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools) though you might change your mind.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest that you just open up Okular and put the windows next to each other. A real PDF viewer is much more useful if you've got a non-trivial document. (What if you want to jump between pages? Search for a string? Zoom in?)

I can't tell which windowing system you're using from the screenshot, but most have a short cut for making a window (well, "frame" in Emacs-parlance) half a screen wide.

Then you'll probably want to set up SyncTex. There's an example for doing that with Evince at [this blog post](http://digsim.is-a-geek.com/blog/synctex-with-emacs-and-evince.html). I don't know much about Okular, but you might have to change the DBus wizardry slightly.

Yes, I understand the motivation to do "everything in Emacs", but people have put quite a lot of effort into writing good PDF / PS viewers. And you don't need to edit anything in them, so keyboard shortcuts don't matter :-)

Comment: blog post is not loading; a common problem in stackoverflow. here is a permalink for the wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20161015025106/http://digsim.is-a-geek.com/blog/synctex-with-emacs-and-evince.html

Comment: For anyone coming here nowadays, modern Emacs has a wonderful library called pdf-tools (https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools). This does things like isearch and is generally a pleasure to use. It might be worth trying out.